# Deadlock when accessing HashSet unless Tokio mutex is used

Tags: asynchronous, rust, deadlock, rust-tokio

I'm getting deadlocked, and I cannot figure out what's the issue.
The code doesn't work if I use `std::Mutex` (or `parking_lot::Mutex`), but it works when Tokio's async mutex is used.

My understanding is that this would imply that I'm holding the lock across the `await` points, but as far as I can tell, I'm not, but clearly, I'm doing something wrong, I just don't see it.

Here is a simplified version of the code:

```
    // This is the callee
    // I am spawning Tokio task for each connection and "inside" the task I'm calling run and awaiting it
    pub async fn run(&mut self) -> Result<(), ConnectionError> {
        self.handshake().await?;
        loop {
            let msg = self
                .connection
                .next()
                .await
                .ok_or(ConnectionError::NoMessage)??; 
            let r = handle_message(msg)?;
            if let Some(r) = r {
                self.connection.send(r).await?;
            }
        }
    }

    //This is function where I have an issue, it is called by `handle_message`
    fn handle_request_by_id(id: u64) -> Result<Self, DecodeError> {
        {
            if IDs.read().contains(id) {
                return Ok(Self::default());
            }
        }

        {
            IDs.write().insert(id);
        }

        //...rest of the logic

}

// Here is the definition of IDs
// RwLock is from parking_lot, the same issue is with the std one
pub static IDs: Lazy<RwLock<HashSet<u64>>> =
    Lazy::new(|| RwLock::new(HashSet::with_capacity(4_000_000)));
```

The same code works if I use `async RwLock` form Tokio. This function is the only one "interacting" with `IDs`, so it is not that I am taking the lock "somewhere else" for too long.

As per Tokio docs:

> As a rule of thumb, using a synchronous mutex from within asynchronous code is fine as long as contention remains low and the lock is not held across calls to .await

I think I am following these rules.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] not just pieces of the puzzle.

Comment: It's probably related to how the `write()` is handled or how many requests you are processing. `write()` will block that tokio thread while the other `read()` operations are happening and depending on configuration that could deadlock. Also `std::sync::RwLock` and `tokio::sync::RwLock` have possibly different write behavior. Tokio guarantees "fair" locking between read and write but its possible the std prioritises reads depending on OS.

Comment: @Michael But the OP said it also doesn't work with `Mutex`, so this cannot be the reason (and `parking_lot`'s is `RwLock` is fair).

Comment: That is correct, the same story is with Mutex (both `std` and `parking_lot`), as well as with eg. DashMap, on both Linux and Mac.  
Since there is a lot of code I'm thinking about how can I add more context without just pasting "everything".  There are _a lot_ of calls to this function from many concurrent tasks.

Comment: Pinpoint the problem by removing code and seeing if the issue persists. If you cannot minimize the problem and you cannot paste all code here (**embedded in the question**), then unfortunately you cannot ask here.

Comment: The code you've shown looks sane to me. You have extremely short critical sections, so using a synchronous lock seems adequate.

Comment: Solved the issue thanks to suggestions by @cafce25 & Chayim Friedman Thanks, everyone!

Comment: Great! You've found the problem by yourself. If you do need the `while` loop, call `tokio::task::yield_now()` between iterations to avoid busy loop.

Answer (score 0):

While trying to improve my question based on feedback from @cafce25, I noticed that `handle_request_by_id` was called in `while` loop, smth. like this:

```
while !ids.empty() {
  handle_request_by_id(ids.next())
}
```

Since `handle_request_by_id` is pretty short, it turns out I was creating a "busy loop", acquiring and dropping locks "immediately".

I've tested my assumption by just handling a single `id` (removing while loop) and everything worked as expected.